# SimpleITK Filtering with sitk.ConnectedThresholdImageFilter() wrong output

Tags: python, medical, medical-imaging, simpleitk

I have tried many things to segment gray_matter, white_matter and cs_fluid images using `sitk.ConnectedThresholdImageFilter()`. unfortunately, I couldn't. Please, let me know what I am doing wrong.

Here is the example code:

```
data_dir = "<path to data dir>"
image_dir = data_dir + "images/" 
image_filenames = sorted(glob.glob(image_dir + '*.nii.gz'))

mask_dir = data_dir + "masks/" 
mask_filenames = sorted(glob.glob(mask_dir + '*.nii.gz'))

image_filename = image_filenames[0]
mask_filename = mask_filenames[0]

image = sitk.ReadImage(image_filename)
mask = sitk.ReadImage(mask_filename)

print("image_filename:", image_filename)
print("Image:")
display_image(image)
print("Mask:")
display_image(mask)

masked_image = sitk.Mask(image, mask)
print("Masked image:")
display_image(masked_image)

gm_filter = sitk.ConnectedThresholdImageFilter()
gm_filter.SetLower(1)  # Lower threshold for GM intensities
gm_filter.SetUpper(100)  # Upper threshold for GM intensities
gm_image = gm_filter.Execute(masked_image)
print("GM image:")
display_image(gm_image)
```

And, here is the output:

Image:
[image]
Mask:
[image]
Masked image:
[image]
GM image:
[image]

It's all good up to "GM image". I really couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong with the `sitk.ConnectedThresholdImageFilter()` method. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do something similar to what I needed by using methods called `sitk.BinaryThreshold()` and `sitk.And()` together.

```
lower_threshold, upper_threshold = 100, 200 # Thresholds for gray matter
gm_image = sitk.BinaryThreshold(image, lower_threshold, upper_threshold, 1, 0)
gm_image = sitk.And(gm_image, mask)

print("GM image:")
display_image(gm_image)
```

Here's the result for the GM image:
[image: Gray matter image]

I still wonder what the problem with `sitk.ConnectedThresholdImageFilter()` is.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the seed point for the region growing, provide a seed point within the region of interest.

You can do that with the `AddSeed` method of the `ConnectedThresholdImageFilter`

edit: lets try the AddSeed method

For example:

```
from glob import glob
import SimpleITK as sitk

data_dir = "<path to data dir>"
image_dir = data_dir + "images/" 
image_filenames = sorted(glob(image_dir + '*.nii.gz'))

mask_dir = data_dir + "masks/" 
mask_filenames = sorted(glob(mask_dir + '*.nii.gz'))

image_filename = image_filenames[0]
mask_filename = mask_filenames[0]

image = sitk.ReadImage(image_filename)
mask = sitk.ReadImage(mask_filename)

masked_image = sitk.Mask(image, mask)

gm_filter = sitk.ConnectedThresholdImageFilter()
gm_filter.SetLower(1)
gm_filter.SetUpper(100)
gm_filter.AddSeed((50, 50, 50))
gm_image = gm_filter.Execute(masked_image)
```

Comment: ```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[67], line 31
     29 gm_filter.SetLower(1)  # Lower threshold for GM intensities
     30 gm_filter.SetUpper(100)  # Upper threshold for GM intensities
---> 31 gm_filter.SetSeed((50, 50, 50))
     32 gm_image = gm_filter.Execute(masked_image)
     33 print("GM image:")

AttributeError: 'ConnectedThresholdImageFilter' object has no attribute 'SetSeed'``` You mean SetSeedList?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Unfortunately, I get the same output as it is now. GM image is a blank image.

Comment: I use BinaryThreshold() and it's doing fine for now btw.

Comment: Do your separate answer and validate it if you think you fixed your problem

Comment: Although it solves my problem, I didn't write it separately as an answer because it is not a final solution and does not explain the problem with the `ConnectedThresholdImageFilter()` method, but if you say so, so be it. I'm still wondering what the problem with sitk.ConnectedThresholdImageFilter() is, btw.